# Generate a pdf using rotativa in asp.net with multiple partial views in one view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf, rotativa

I am trying to generate a pdf using rotativa in asp.net. My view has multiple partial views rendered on it. I am able to create a pdf of single partial views but when i am combine all the partial views and trying to generate the pdf. It generates the pdf before loading the data in the pdf. please suggest how to hold the process until the loading of data in the pdf. 
Thanks in advance.

```
    public ActionResult Followers()
    {
        MediaAPIController mac = new MediaAPIController();
        JsonResult jR = mac.getUserInfo("", "", "", "201");
        MediaLibrary.User u = (MediaLibrary.User)jR.Data;
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(async delegate
        {
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            return 42;
        }).Wait();

        return new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("PreviewPdf", u)
        {
            FileName = "MyDoc.pdf",
            PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.A4,
            PageOrientation = Rotativa.Options.Orientation.Portrait,
            PageMargins = { Left = 10, Right = 10 }
        };
    }
```

Comment: You should move the getUserInfo function into a service and not mass around with the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ViewAsPdf** method instead of **ActionAsPdf** and pass the model that are bind in partial views. In this way the view will be bind before rendering and problem will be solved.

Comment: Thank you Manprit Singh, but it is taking so much time to print the data on pdf.

Comment: Currently, I am using 
return new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf("_Activity", u) {
FileName = "MyDoc.pdf",
CustomSwitches = " DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "  Page: [page]/[toPage]\" --enable-javascript --debug-javascript --no-background " + " --javascript-delay 1500000 --images --print-media-type --enable-forms " + " --orientation \"Portrait\" --margin-left \"10\" --margin-right \"10\" --page-size \"A4\"" };

But still it only prints few lines of data not the complete data in the pdf. Is there any way to improve the execution process.?

Comment: Can you post any sample project so that i can review the code and work around?